# Determination of the variability of different spectra over shorter wavelength ranges from that of a single spectrum?

Tags: atmospheric-science, spectroscopy

To pictographically explain, how do you convert Fig. 1 to Fig. 2?

[image]

Fig. 1

to

[image]

Fig. 2

Comment: Given the Fig2, and partial pressures for all those gases, you could construct Fig1. The other way around is more challenging - Probably with some PCA? Fig1 seems to be irradiance, so you'd need an irradiance spectrum outwside the atmosphere to get a handle on what was absorbed, then compare that 'missing piece' to the various absorption spectra. But if your question is whether it is possible to go from an absorption spectrum of a mixture to the absorption spectra of the components, thats impossible, if you do not have extra information.

Comment: @bukwyrm Could you elucidate?

Comment: something like this: https://www.osapublishing.org/viewmedia.cfm?r=1&rwjcode=ao&uri=ao-45-32-8374&html=true

Comment: @bukwyrm Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly derive the information in picture 2 from picture 1, because they show different things.

The first image shows spectral radiance, the second set of images shows opacities (or rather absorption coefficients) for specific atmospheric constituents.  The top graph can be either measured or simulated.  The second graph can only be calculated using a radiative transfer model.